# error handling in knockout spa using amd and requirejs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application

So I have a fairly large Single-Page-Application based on [Steve Sandersons SPA template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/).  custom bindingHandlers, validation etc all working fine.

We require the use of the XMLHttpRequests, Session and Local storage as well as some other libraries that don't have universal support (jquery 2.0 etc).  I have a core module which handles identity and exposes a few services and both of these are reliant on these features. This is loaded when the user first visits the page.

I have an issue with older browsers where either a) they don't support some of the modules being loaded so they throw an error before hitting the onload function, or b) it hits the onload function but they don't support the browser features so I need to raise an exception myself and handle it in some manner.

Example: IE8 throws an 'Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'' (jquery error) and IE9 Doesn't support everything I need so I throw a custom error.

```
define('core', ['jquery', 'browser'], function($, browser) {
     if(!browser.hasFullSupport) {
         throw new Error('Update your browser');
     }
     // aload of gubbins that requires sessionStorage etc
     return {
          identity: identity,
          serviceA: serviceA,
          serviceB: serviceB
     }
}, function(err) {
    // doesn't catch the ie8 error here
});
```

I've tried setting a window.onerror but it works differently across browser versions and in some I can't capture the error message properly, I just get a 'Script Error'.

I know I can add an error event handler for the module definitions but it doesn't capture the errors i'm experiencing.

I've seen people use

```
requirejs.onError = function(err) {
   // something here 
}
```

but i'm using the requirejs gulp bundler and I can't see where this object would exposed (if it is at all)

```
var require = {
baseUrl: ".",
paths: {
    "modernizr":            "bower_modules/modernizr/modernizr",
    "browser":              "app/browser-detect",
    "crossroads":           "bower_modules/crossroads/dist/crossroads.min",
    "hasher":               "bower_modules/hasher/dist/js/hasher.min",
    "jquery":               "bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
    ....

// gulpfile
var requireJsRuntimeConfig = vm.runInNewContext(fs.readFileSync('src/app/require.config.js') + '; require;');
requireJsOptimizerConfig = merge(requireJsRuntimeConfig, {
    out: 'scripts.js',
    baseUrl: './src',
    name: 'app/startup',
    paths: {
        requireLib: 'bower_modules/requirejs/require'
    },
    include: [
        'requireLib',
        'components/nav-bar/nav-bar',
        .....

gulp.task('js', function () {
return rjs(requireJsOptimizerConfig)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

There's loads of components/pages and each could throw an error, but it's this initial core component loading that i'm keen to sort out.  I'd like to distinguish between errors (that may or may not be caused by the browser being too old) and between me detecting that they're too old before hand, is there an elegant way to achieve this using this template model?

I'd rather not deviate too far from the template as i'm not too familiar with requirejs / gulp etc but i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You contradict yourself:

> We require the use of the XMLHttpRequests, Session and Local storage as well as some other libraries that don't have universal support (jquery 2.0 etc)

But:

> IE8 throws an 'Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'' (jquery error) and IE9 Doesn't support everything I need so I throw a custom error.

You can't use libraries and HTML 5 features for newer browsers and expect older browsers to still work. Libraries that do not support legacy browsers like IE 8 do not fail gracefully so you cannot handle the failure very well. And even if you found a workaround to somehow circumvent the errors, you would still need to test them all in old browsers periodically which beats the intent to support only newer browsers.

So I recommend you two approaches:

1. Either decide not to support olders browsers at all and test the app only in newest modern browsers. You could use modern versions of libraries that dropped support of old browsers and not worry about old browsers at all. It depends on the state of your user base. Or:
2. Downgrade libraries to versions that support your minimal required browsers and continue developing the app with them. Test the app and fix all errors that occur in old browsers. Use polyfills that enable new HTML 5 features in old browsers via emulation.

Comment: You're right, it is a contradiction and i'm not trying to support IE8 or IE9 at all, but I am looking for a graceful way of being able to redirect them to an 'upgrade your browser' page in some manner.  Even though we explicitly state they must use a modern browser, most of our support calls are from people using older browsers.  Just trying to nip that in the bud.

Comment: You can use window.onerror callback, but be careful to differentiate between ordinary errors and errors due to an old browser so that you don't show "upgrade your browser" to a Chrome user because your JavaScript crashed.

Comment: I think detecting some of the old browsers from a user agent on the server side and not loading the SPA at all would be a safer bet.

Comment: I had thought about this, but I didn't want the headache of checking mobile browsers as well. i'll try out some more on both but after playing with it again today I don't think I have a lot of choice.  Thanks for your help anyways.